# How to export a binary movie?

Tags: export, animation

I have a table of binary images and want to export them as a binary movie, but I can only export RGB movie instead of a binary one and the size of the movie is really large. Is there any way to export a binary movie?

Thanks,
Liu

```
Movie = Table[MorphologicalTransform[Binarize[Import["E:\\McMaster\\Convert
Movie\\dead non-magnetic no field 3.avi", {"Frames", {i}}], Method -> "Entropy"], 
"Clean"], {i, 1, 10}]

BinaryImageQ[Movie[[10]]]

Export["E:\\McMaster\\Convert Movie\\dead non-magnetic no field 3 B&W2.avi",
Movie[[1 ;; 10]], "FrameRate" -> 113];
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently, even if you explicitly feed a list of binary images to `Export[]`, the colorspace of the resulting file is still RGB. Oh well.

Comment: Yes, they don't have the option of B&W in the color space.

Answer (score 1):

The exported colors space for the PNG gets adapted if one choses maximal compression (PNG is lossless, btw.)

```
n = 200;
a = Image[CrossMatrix[{n, n}], "Binary"];
images = Table[ImageRotate[a, 6 2. Pi/360 i], {i, 1, 360}];
Export["a.png", images, "CompressionLevel" -> 1];

Import["a.png", "Summary"]
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this can work for an image but not for a movie since the color space supported by Mathematica doesn't include Black&White.

Comment: That's a multi-page PNG. Browser will play that as animation in the same way as animated GIF. Indeed, Mathematica's video capacities are very limited. But you can turn that PNG into any video format with the freely available, very powerful command line tool [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org).

Comment: Yeah, sure! Thanks for helping!

Comment: You're welcome!